# When I run inception preprocessing script, it fails

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, bazel, imagenet

When I run `bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet "${DATA_DIR}"` the error message:

```
bazel-bin/inception/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet: line 66: bazel-bin/inception/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet.runfiles_make_/inception/inception/data
/download_imagenet.sh: No such file or directory
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I followed the instructions at [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception)

Comment: Did you make sure you were in the right directory before running the commands? Not sure why it would try to run `/download_imagenet.sh` otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow's models repository has a very confusing structure, and you're in the wrong directory.  The tree looks like this:

```
models/
  BUILD
  WORKSPACE
  inception/
    BUILD
    WORKSPACE
    inception/
      data/
        ...
```

I'm pretty if you ran `pwd` it would say `models`.  However, the `download_and_preprocess_imagenet` assumes you'll be in `models/inception`.  So, do:

```
 cd inception
 bazel build //inception:download_and_preprocess_imagenet
```

Then `bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet` should work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a beginner to tensorflow, but this helped a lot. I was wondering how it was possible to run `build_image_data.py` too. I tried running a similar script, but it did not work.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't designed for back-and-forth mailing-list-style Q&A. You should probably either file a new question (with info about the error you're seeing) or edit this question to include additional information (if you think the issues are all part of one larger question). Also, if my answer solved your issue, please accept my answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for your help!